# Multiple bars on a single plot (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble arranging data correctly. I have 3 plots for every x value but at the moment they are all plotting over themselves. I can't seem to find a way to get them to move on the axis so that they align next to each other.

[image]

This is how it has come out, whereas I'd like it to come out like this:

[image]

Don't worry about the color I just haven't added that yet. I have looked at other peoples examples but it doesn't seem to help.

He is the code I use to generate this graph:

```
In[15]: for i in df_Entry.columns.levels[0]:
    plt.figure()
    barwidth = 0.2
    df_Entry[i]['mean'].plot(kind='bar', yerr=df_Entry[i]['std'])
    df_Apex[i]['mean'].plot(kind='bar', yerr=df_Apex[i]['std'])
    df_Exit[i]['mean'].plot(kind='bar', yerr=df_Exit[i]['std'])
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
b1 = np.array([1,2,3])
b2 = np.array([3,2,1])
x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
plt.bar(left=x-0.3, width=0.3, height=b1)
plt.bar(left=x, width=0.3, height=b2, color='g')
```

the `plt.bar()` command lets you specify where the left side of your bars is, so you can just shift it by a given amount. One drawback here is that the x axis is a floating-point axis, which you may not want.

There's a solution to that, too, though it does not come from me:
http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/pcfb/numpympl/MatplotlibBarPlots.html

This uses the object-oriented interface of pyplot (which confuses some people but is actually very cool), to change labels and axis limits after the fact.